# Grouping select output by null value in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

The simplified version is this: I have a table with two fields. The first field, `trx`, will always have a value. The second field, `tstop`, can be either null or a timestamp.

I would like to organize the output from the select such that the first "group" of records all have tstop of null, the remaining records have a non-null value of `tstop`. Each group is ordered by `trx` desc.

How is this done?

```
TABLE rx
(
  recid serial NOT NULL,
  trx timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  tstop timestamp without time zone
)

Example values:
recid    trx                      tstop
36;      "2014-06-10 13:05:16";   "";
113759;  "2014-06-10 13:05:16";   "";
33558;   "2014-03-31 18:08:15";   "2014-03-31 18:08:15";
12535;   "2014-03-31 18:08:15";   "";
660;     "2014-03-31 18:05:59";   "";
144209;  "2014-03-30 19:21:14";   "";
```

Desired Output:

```
 recid         trx                  tstop
 36;      "2014-06-10 13:05:16";   "";
 113759;  "2014-06-10 13:05:16";   "";
 12535;   "2014-03-31 18:08:15";   "";
 660;     "2014-03-31 18:05:59";   "";
 144209;  "2014-03-30 19:21:14";   "";
 33558;   "2014-03-31 18:08:15";   "2014-03-31 18:08:15";
```

This obviously will not work:

```
select * from rx order by trx desc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `IS NULL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM rx
ORDER BY tstop IS NULL DESC, trx DESC
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/11159/1/0)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Just `order by` the columns and use the option `nulls first` to make `null` values appear first:

```
SELECT *
FROM rx
ORDER BY tstop DESC NULLS FIRST, trx DESC
```

Comment: `NULLS FIRST` is nice option, but check **[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/28e5a0/3/0)** last two records, OP wants grouping by NULL/NOT NULL and order by trx DESC

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY (CASE WHEN tstop IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC, 
         tstop DESC